# UIAlertView doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uialertview

I have an alert view with the two buttons, but the buttons don't open the urls. I don't know the error. Help please.

Here's the code:

```
-(IBAction)showAlertView {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Obrir en..."
                          message:@"Es pot requirir la aplicació de Google Maps"
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Millor no..."
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Mapes",@"Google Maps",nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Mapes"])
    {
        UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        NSString *ourPath = @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=Plaça+del+Rei+43003+Tarragona";
        NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
        [ourApplication openURL:ourURL]; 
    }
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Google Maps"])
    {
        UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        NSString *ourPath = @"comgooglemaps://?daddr=Plaça+del+Rei+43003+Tarragona&directionsmode=walking";
        NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
        [ourApplication openURL:ourURL];
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing looks obviously wrong. Try putting breakpoints in your `alertVew:clickedButtonAtIndex:` function to see exactly what is happening

Comment: Set a break point in your alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: method and trace through.  What is the title that's returned?  Does it match and step into your if block(s)?

Comment: make usre url does not have any space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the special character (ç) in the address is throwing the NSURL off. Try using the `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method of NSString to encode it before passing it to the NSURL initializer.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the URL which we fired.

```
if([ourApplication canOpenURL:ourURL])
    [ourApplication openURL:ourURL];
else
    NSLog(@"URL is not valid.");
```

As I check with both URL, they are not able to open.
You can check the URL with above code whether URL is able to open or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the URL's, try this:

```
-(IBAction)showAlertView {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Obrir en..."
                          message:@"Es pot requirir la aplicació de Google Maps"
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Millor no..."
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Mapes",@"Google Maps",nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    //0 is cancel
    if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        [self openURLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Pla%C3%A7a+del+Rei+43003+Tarragona&data=!1m4!1m3!1d4618!2d1.2582895!3d41.1168719!4m11!1m10!4m8!1m3!1d26081603!2d-95.677068!3d37.0625!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!17b1"];       
    }
    if(buttonIndex == 2)
    {
        [self openURLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d18473!2d1.258181!3d41.1168316!4m13!3m12!1m0!1m1!1sPla%C3%A7a+del+Rei+43003+Tarragona!3m8!1m3!1d26081603!2d-95.677068!3d37.0625!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1&fid=0"];

    }
}

- (void)openURLWithString:(NSString *)string{

    UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSString *ourPath = string;
    NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];

    if([ourApplication canOpenURL:ourURL])

        [ourApplication openURL:ourURL];
    else
        NSLog(@"URL is not valid.");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use `elseif` in your second condition, because you only want to fire the second if the first isn't true. Second, it seems to be the URL you're using in @"Mapes"... I tested this and that URL seems to be the culprit. When I changed that URL to another test URL, it worked.